# Polymer 1.0 conditional works in reverse first

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a conditional (if) for a polymer-radio-group and a paper-checkbox. Essentially when a certain radio is selected and a checkbox is checked, a value is displayed. What I want is, when a radio is first selected, then the checkbox, a value is returned. See code:

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    <paper-radio-group selected="{{selection}}">
      <paper-radio-button name="a">A</paper-radio-button>
       <paper-radio-button name="b">B</paper-radio-button>
    </paper-radio-group>
    <paper-item>
        <paper-item-body>
          Foo
        </paper-item-body>
        <paper-checkbox id="checkbox" label="Enable" checked="{{alpha_checked}}"></paper-checkbox>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
        is: "my-app",
        properties: {
          selection: {
            type: String,
            observer: "selectionChanged"
          },
          alpha_checked: {
            observer: "selectionChanged"
          }
        },
        selectionChanged: function (newval, oldval) {
          if ( newval === "b" && this.alpha_checked === true ) {
             alert("You have selected 'B' and ticked 'Foo'.");
          }
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

If I ticked "Foo" then "A", the alert shows but if the reverse, nothing alerts. Is something wrong with the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

I have drunk a cup of coffee and saw a work around:

```
selectionChanged: function () {
   if ( this.selection === "b" && this.alpha_checked === true ) {
      alert("You have selected 'B' and ticked 'Foo'.");
}
```

Hope someone finds this useful in the future.